# PushWoosh & Ionic - Save User Device Token in Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, pushwoosh

I actually use PushWoosh with Ionic and it's work like a charm ! I can send Push with PushWoosh Dashboard and my 2 device receive them (Android, and iOS).

The problem start when I want save the user device_token into Firebase, I'll try this :

```
    pushNotification.getPushToken(
    function(status)
      {
    var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
    $scope.deviceToken = deviceToken;
      userRef.child(authResponse.userID).update({ device_token: $scope.deviceToken })
      }
    );
```

But I have error message :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushNotification' of undefined

When I lauch app with my phone, I can see Device_Token, but I want save him in Firebase ...

Please help !

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to initialize pushNotification variable?